# PostgreSQL parsing multiple DB columns with same xml name

Tags: xml, postgresql, parsing, xpath

Is there a way to parse xml using xpath when xml like:

```
<foos type="array">
    <foo>
    <name>bar</name>
    </foo>
    <foo>
    <name>bar2</name>
    </foo>
</foos>
```

Basically, different values of bar exist for the same name and are provided as shown above. I would like to store them in a postgres table so that column1 = "_1", value1 = "bar", column2 = "_2", value2 = "bar2".

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no easy way to do that automatically; PostgreSQL isn't good at generating tables with dynamic columns. Start by extracting the XML to key/value pairs. Then pivot it, manually or using something like the `crosstab` function from the `tablefunc` extension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but you'll get the string `'bar'` with the XPath expression

```
string(/foos/foo[1]/name)
```

and the string `'bar2'` with

```
string(/foos/foo[2]/name)
```